# Failed to parse wsdl: Found more than one wsdl:portType

Tags: soap-api, wsdl2apex

While parsing the wsdl document from local storage i got this below error

> Failed to parse wsdl: Found more than one wsdl:portType. WSDL with
>   multiple portType not supported

And so could not parse and create class for the WSDL.

Comment: not all WSDL features are supported by wsdl2apex, you can get them out of the WSDL to use wsdl2Apex and then manually add anything that needs to be added.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution is that the wsdl should not contain multiple **wsdl:portType** and  **wsdl:binding**

So remove the unwanted ***wsdl:portType*** and its respective ***wsdl:binding***

Answer (score 3):

There are many [restrictions on what WSDL can be handled](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_callouts_wsdl2apex.htm) by the Apex tooling including:

> WSDL files with mulitple portTypes, multiple services, or multiple
>   bindings

You may be able to edit down the WSDL to something that the tooling does support, but you will have to learn more about the [elements in a WSDL file](http://www.w3.org/TR/wsdl) than you probably want to before attempting that.

Answer (score 3):

I've made a free alternative version of Wsdl2Apex that can work around the limitations of WSDLs with multiple `wsdl:portType` definitions.

You can get it from - [FuseIT SFDC Explorer](http://www.fuseit.com/explorer) (Disclosure, this is my current employer).

It will ignore all but the supported SOAP ports. E.g. It will skip the SOAP 1.2 port, so you don't need to modify the WSDL by hand first.

Answer (score 1):

Let me explain here with an example. Sometimes you can see multiple binding in wsdls as shown below.

I have taken this wsdl from `http://www.dneonline.com/calculator.asmx?WSDL` for reference. You can see there are two  `<wsdl:binding` and  `<wsdl:port` tag present. Just delete the second `<wsdl:binding` and  `<wsdl:port` node and try to parse again. It will work. Similarly you can update the wsdl and try again. hope this will work.

**Original wsdl**

```
  <wsdl:binding name="CalculatorSoap" type="tns:CalculatorSoap">
    <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
    <wsdl:operation name="Add">
      <soap:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/Add" style="document" />
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="Subtract">
      <soap:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/Subtract" style="document" />
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="Multiply">
      <soap:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/Multiply" style="document" />
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="Divide">
      <soap:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/Divide" style="document" />
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
  <wsdl:binding name="CalculatorSoap12" type="tns:CalculatorSoap">
    <soap12:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
    <wsdl:operation name="Add">
      <soap12:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/Add" style="document" />
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap12:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap12:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="Subtract">
      <soap12:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/Subtract" style="document" />
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap12:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap12:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="Multiply">
      <soap12:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/Multiply" style="document" />
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap12:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap12:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="Divide">
      <soap12:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/Divide" style="document" />
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap12:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap12:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
  <wsdl:service name="Calculator">
    <wsdl:port name="CalculatorSoap" binding="tns:CalculatorSoap">
      <soap:address location="http://www.dneonline.com/calculator.asmx" />
    </wsdl:port>
    <wsdl:port name="CalculatorSoap12" binding="tns:CalculatorSoap12">
      <soap12:address location="http://www.dneonline.com/calculator.asmx" />
    </wsdl:port>
 </wsdl:service>
```

**Updated wsdl**

```
  <wsdl:binding name="CalculatorSoap" type="tns:CalculatorSoap">
    <soap:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
    <wsdl:operation name="Add">
      <soap:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/Add" style="document" />
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="Subtract">
      <soap:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/Subtract" style="document" />
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="Multiply">
      <soap:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/Multiply" style="document" />
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
    <wsdl:operation name="Divide">
      <soap:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/Divide" style="document" />
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
  <wsdl:service name="Calculator">
    <wsdl:port name="CalculatorSoap" binding="tns:CalculatorSoap">
      <soap:address location="http://www.dneonline.com/calculator.asmx" />
    </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>
```